# How do I test AngularJS trusted html with Jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I would like to use Jasmine to ensure an html data value has been correctly trusted by AngularJS.

**Code**

The code below fetches an `article` via an external api and uses Angular's `$sce` to trust the html content held in `article.Body`.

```
getArticle: ->
    defer = @$q.defer()
    @getContent(url).then (result) =>
        article = result.data
        article.Body = @$sce.trustAsHtml article.Body
        defer.resolve article
    defer.promise
```

This code works and, as I step through it, I can see the data is returned and the html property `article.Body` has been correctly trusted. Now I would like to write a unit-test that confirms this.

**Unit-Test**

Here is my attempt at the jasmine unit-test:

```
describe 'when getArticle is called with valid articleId', ->
    it "should call getContent and return article with trusted html", ->
        getContentDefer = @$q.defer()
        spyOn(@contentService, 'getContent').andReturn getContentDefer.promise

        article = {Id:'1', Body: '<div>test</div>'}  

        @contentService.getArticle(article.Id).then (response) =>
            expect(response.Body instanceof TrustedValueHolderType).toBeTruthy()

        getContentDefer.resolve {data:article}
        @$rootScope.$digest()
```

You can see that I am attempting to ensure that the returned `response.Body` is an instance of the AngularJS type: `TrustedValueHolderType`. I do not know if this is a good idea but anyway, it does not work and I receive the following error:

```
ReferenceError: TrustedValueHolderType is not defined
```

I was hoping there was a neat way, perhaps a boolean flag, that I could use to determine whether the `article.Body` is trusted html or just a plain html string.

**Update**

The accepted answer below (thanks @avowkind) gave me the hint I needed. The trick is to use the `$sce.getTrustedHtml()` method which takes the `TrustedValueHolderType` and returns the original html value. Perfect.

**Passing Unit-Test**

```
ddescribe 'getArticle', ->
    it "should return an article with trusted html", ->
        getContentDefer = @$q.defer()
        spyOn(@contentService, 'getContent').andReturn getContentDefer.promise
        body = '<div>test</div>'
        article = {Id:'1', Body: body}
        @contentService.getArticle(article.Id, @token).then (response) =>
            expect(@$sce.getTrustedHtml(response.Body)).toEqual(body)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am able to jasmine unit test my filter by using $sce.getTrustedHtml on the output of the filter.  This works fine if you know how to inject the $sce service into the test.

e.g

```
/** 
 * A filter used to wrap code in the <pre> tag
 */ 
myApp.filter( 'code', ['$sce', function($sce) {
      return function(input) {
          var html = (input != "")? '<pre>' + input + '</pre>' : input;
          return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
          
      };
}]);

// test output
it('wraps pre around input: ', function() {
   expect($sce.getTrustedHtml(codeFilter("Hello"))).toEqual("<pre>Hello</pre>");
} );
```

This works for my local system tests.  However I tried to build an example fiddle with it
http://jsfiddle.net/avowkind/vfWr3/1/

and this returns an error:

> Unknown provider: $sceProvider <- $sce

if anyone can fix the fiddle that would be great.

Comment: I have updated your fiddle so it now shows passing tests (see http://jsfiddle.net/vfWr3/7/). I updated your external refs to use the latest version of angular, added an external ref to the `angular-sanitize.js` lib (required for `$sce`) and added the `'ngSanitize'` injection ref to your app module declaration :-)

Comment: `$sce.getTrustedHtml()` did the trick. See Updated unit test above.